# Problems with executing running rails server : Rails 5.1.3 on windows 10 x-64

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Could not find gem 'puma (~> 3.7) x86-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

Comment: Have you tried to bundle install to install the missing gems?

Answer (score 2):

In order to use Puma gem on Windows, you have to installed Devkit and OpenSSL installed.

To Install Puma gem:

1. Install DevKit. It should be in folder `c:\devkit`
2. install openssl package. `c:\openssl`
3. You need to copy the `ddls` from the bin directory (`libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll`) to your ruby/bin directory.
4. open a windows console
5. initialize the DevKit build environment
   `c:\devkit\devkitvars.bat`
6. Now it’s possible to install the puma gem with the OpenSSL packages
   `gem install puma -- --with-opt-dir=c:\openssl`